# Верно ли составлено предложение?

Tags: согласование

Многие ошибочно полагают, что, **заплатив** фотографу за фотосъемку, **можно использовать** фотографии как угодно.

Верно ли согласуются выделенные слова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верно.
"заплатив, можно использовать". Вариант - "можно, заплатив, использовать" или "можно использовать, заплатив".  Согласование такое же.
 В чем сомнения?

> То есть сомнения в том,
> можно ли с этим деепричастием употребить
> безличное "можно"? или все же лучше
> указать конкретно, кто может использовать
> фото?

- По-моему, никаких шероховатостей нет.  У Вас деепричастный оборот внутри придаточного дополнительного, а что оно безличное, так и ничего, подлежащее "Многие" осталось в главном, всё здесь хорошо. Сравните: 
  "...всякого интенданта,
  прослужившего престол-отечеству более
  одного года, **можно** немедленно
  вешать на оглобле, нимало **не рискуя** ошибиться." (А. В. Суворов) :)

UPD 
Если сомнения не развеялись, можно переподчинить деепричастие:

Многие, заплатив фотографу за фотосъемку, ошибочно полагают, что могут (или: они вправе?) использовать фотографии как угодно.

Comment: "Заплатив, люди могут использовать фотографии..." То есть сомнения в том, можно ли с этим деепричастием употребить безличное "можно"? или все же лучше указать конкретно, кто может использовать фото?

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!